# Передача массива checkbox (метод $_POST)

Tags: php, html

Задача: передать массив checkbox обработчику таким образом, чтобы у меня были данные о каждом флажке.

Суть:
У меня есть текстовый файл, в котором n-ое количество строк (заведомо количество строк неизвестно). Я их вывожу на страницу следующим образом:

```
$f = 'temp.txt';
$temp = file($f);
$date = count($arr); // количество строк в файле temp.txt

for ( $i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) { 
    $read = $arr_temp[$i];
    $string = substr($read, 20, -2); 
    //припудрим строки
    $trans = array("/" => ".", "," => " ", "\"" => "");
    $print = strtr($string, $trans);    
    ?>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=1 /> <? echo $print . "<br />"; ?> </p>
    <?
}
```

***Ребята, если я делаю неправильно - поправьте меня!***

Эти строки надо удалить. Поэтому по кнопке "Delete" мы переходим к обработчику, который имеет вид:

```
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
$f = 'temp.txt';
$temp = file($f);
$date = count($arr); // количество строк в файле temp.txt
$file = fopen("id4del.lst", "w+");

if(empty($checkbox)) {
    echo("You do not choose." . $checkbox = 0 . "<br /> ");
} else {
    $N = count($checkbox);
    echo("You choosed $N strings:" . "<br /> ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++) {
        $check = $checkbox[$i];
        echo("Line $i :" . $check ."<br /> ");
    //    echo($check . "<br /> ");
        $iddel = substr($temp[$i], 0, 10); 
        fwrite($file, $iddel . "\n"); //запись в файл ревизий выбранных на удаление строк        
        } 
    }
```

Но, к сожалению, у меня передается только количество отмеченных checkbox и поэтому, если я отметила 2 флажка, допустим, на 5 и 8 позициях, то и удалятся 2 строки, НО 1-ая и 2-ая.

Помогите разобраться и СДЕЛАТЬ, чтобы всё было в соответствие, т.е.:
Выбран флажок 5 - удалим строку 5,
Выбран флажок 8 - удалим строку 8.

Я пробовала делать цикл снаружи, а внутри условие. Но, видимо, я ещё тот рукож**, что у меня ничего не вышло.

Comment: У Вас все checbox одинаковые: `<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=1 />`. Чтобы знать, как ой удалить должна быть хоть какая-то разница между ними. Поставьте порядковый номер чекбокса в `value`. `<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=1 /><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=2 /><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=3 />` и т.д.

Comment: То есть, вы предлагаете в зависимости от количества строк вводить такое же количество <input ... >? Я заведомо не знаю сколько строк попадет в temp.txt. Их там может быть несколько десятков. В value можно сделать массив?

Comment: Ну да У каждой строчки стоит чекбокс с порядковым номером строчки. Тогда в обработчик придет массив с номерами строчек... А разве Вам не так надо?

Comment: Понимаете, это тогда надо сделать несколько десяткой copy-past с input, что неудобно, т.к. большинство могут не пригодиться. Если есть способ из value сделать массив, то можно попробовать. Но я такого не встречала. А может обработчик у меня корявый?

Comment: зачем несколько `десятков copy-past`? У Вас же массив... Вы создаете чекбоксы, передаете в обработчик массив тех боксов, что отмечены, потом прикручиваетесь через этот массив и номера заносите в файл. Все у вас правильно продумано...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=1 /> <? echo $print . "<br />"; ?> </p>
```

на

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=<?php echo $i; ?> /> <? echo $print . "<br />"; ?> </p>
```

чтобы в checkbox`ы передавались номера строк.
HTML должен быть примерно такой:

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=1 />  Line 1
 <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=2 />  Line 2
 <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=3 />  Line 3
```

В этом случае обработчик будет примерно так:

```
$file = fopen("id4del.lst", "w+");
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']; // здесь будет массив с номерами строк с отмеченными чекбоксами

if(!Count($checkbox)) { // если ни один бокс не выделен
    echo("You did not choose any checkbox<br /> ");
} else {
    foreach($checkbox as $lineNum) { // прокручиваемся через боксы 
        echo("Line " . $lineNum ."<br /> "); // вывод на экран 
        fwrite($file, "Line to delete: " . $lineNum . "\n"); //запись в файл ревизий выбранных на удаление строк        
    } 
}
```

Comment: Вот через foreach я вчера вечером пробовала. Но если я проверю temp.txt и в нем окажется 20 строк, то надо будет менять форму, чтобы дописать ещё 17 Input-ов?

Comment: не надо менять форму... Вы создаете список строк и, соответственно, чекбоксов из файла...  Если в `temp.txt` - 20 строк, ваш код создаст 20 чекбоксов... главное, чтобы они были того вида, что я Вам привет - номер строки должен быть в `value`

Comment: Ох, спасибо большое.) Получилось. Теперь осталось командник подцепить и дело в шляпе. Лалала.)

Comment: @Юленька, пожалуйста пометьте ответ полезным (стрелочка вверх) и отвеченным (зеленая галочка) - это поможет нам закрывать решенные вопросы. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=1 /> <? echo $print . "<br />"; ?> </p>
```

на

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=<?php echo $i; ?> /> <? echo $print . "<br />"; ?> </p>
```

чтобы в checkbox`ы передавались номера строк.

Comment: Спасибо большущее за помощь! =)